# In Kotlin how do I open a link in new Window

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am a tyro in `Kotlin` but I have a good Knowledge of `Android` and `Core java`. I am stuck on one condition while developing an android app via the `Kotlin` assistance.

I want that when user clicks a link present on the `pdf` document; the link should be opened on a browser (**and if browser is opened then the link should open on the *new window* not new tab of the same window** ).

I have achieved much of my objective but I didn't found out **how to open a link in the new Window if the browser is open already?**

I have tried the code below(when the link on the `pdf` is clicked then it redirects to the below function call):

```
fun web_page_open(urls: String) { // for more than one url
    val uris = Uri.parse(urls)
    val intents = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uris)
    startActivity(intents)
}
```

I have tried my level-best to explain my problem and also searched a lot(on `github` as well) but all my efforts went in vein.

Any help is warmly welcomed.

**EDIT**: Let's consider an instance if the user has already opened the default browser (say ABZfox) then when the link inside the `pdf`(or a doc) is clicked then the new Window of **ABZfox** opens instead of the same window in which the user was previously working. I'm sure the question makes some sense now!!!

Comment: In which browser having new window functionality?

Comment: You can't get new instance of browser and launch new window. If you need totally new window use your's activity with kind of pdf reader

Comment: Sir(@Mohit Suthar) what does that mean?

Comment: Means, I think default crome brouser not having a new window functionality, you can open new tab instead

Comment: Sir(Stanislav Bondar) but I think that I used this functionality many times but not in kotlin!!! Sir I want that if the browser is opened already then this link should open in new Window and it is possible across many platforms.Isn't it?

Comment: Sir(@Mohit Suthar) lets consider that the user has made Chrome his default browser then it can be done?

Comment: You can open a new tab not new window

Answer (score 14):

You can try this one, might be helpful, open new **tab** of web browser like

```
fun openNewTabWindow(urls: String, context : Context) {
    val uris = Uri.parse(urls)
    val intents = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uris)
    val b = Bundle()
    b.putBoolean("new_window", true)
    intents.putExtras(b)
    context.startActivity(intents)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious time Sir but I have worked that out already!!!Also I think I need to dig deeper myself and get it done.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, because I don't understand where it goes in the code, or when and where to reference this function once it's defined.

Answer (score 0):

You may use chrome custom tabs instead
To use it you need to add below dependency to your gradle

> ```
> compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.1.1'
> ```

Now use below code to open the url

```
 CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        builder.enableUrlBarHiding();
        builder.setShowTitle(true);
        builder.setToolbarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(getActivity(), Uri.parse(url));
```